# python docx changing text when outputting table cells

Tags: python-docx

I am using the python docx package basic example for reading table cell text.
The document is 40MB. However even when split I find this is happening too.

`
from docx import Document
import re

```
wordDoc = Document('./mydoc.docx')
for table in wordDoc.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            print(cell.text)
```

`

The document has the below text "(3.4.2:2) WCS allows an..."
However when output from the example code it converts it to this for some reason

"(:) WCS allows an..."

Does anyone know how I can stop this? Is it a bug or something potentially in the document?
There are other similar cells that don't have this issue, but no pattern to what is causing it.

Tried cutting document down in case it was size related, however still happens.

Answer (score 0):

Found that there was a hidden link in these as part of the index.  I did ctrl + A to select the whole document. Then CTRL+6 to remove all links.

Then processing of the document looked correct.